# Kings Drinking Game

Tags: java, optimization, game, collections, playing-cards

This Review Request evolves into [this Review Request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32348/kings-drinking-game-review-request-2-0-jform-gui) now with a custom UI and other changes.

I wrote  a program to simulate the drinking card game Kings. This is my third Java Project. I didn't quite understand how to create the classes `Card` and `Deck`.  I was struggling to create them so I went ahead and used someones code who had made them in a tutorial. But I think I get it now.

I plan on adding a main menu in the `PSVM` under a `while-true` `loop` with a similar structure to the one in `playGame()`.

I would like a review of my code and some pointers on making it more efficient, cleaner, easier to read, or any other general pointers you have.

The explanation of the game is in the code comment box here:

```
 /**
 * @author              :KyleMHB
 * Project Number       :0003
 * Project Name         :Kings
 * IDE                  :NETBEANS
 * Goal of Project      - 
 * Kings is a rule based drinking game using cards for 4+ players.
 * The Rules are read in from a rules.txt so that one can easily change the rules.
 * How the game works:
 * Players shuffle a deck of cards, place a glass between them and circle the
 * cards around the base of the glass.
 * The players then take turns picking cards, each card has its own rule associated to it.
 * Most importantly, there are 4 Kings, each time a King is picked, 
 * the player who picked it can pour as much of his/her drink into the glass between
 * them as they wish.
 * The game ends when the fourth and final King is picked.
 * The player to pick the final King must down the glass in the center of table.
 */
```

---

**Card Class:**

```
public static class Card {
        private int rank, suit;

        private  String[] suits = { "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs" };
        private  String[] ranks  = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
                                     "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

        Card(int suit, int rank){
                this.rank=rank;
                this.suit=suit;
        }
        public @Override String toString(){
                  return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
        }
        public int getRank() {
                 return rank;
        }
        public int getSuit() {
                return suit;
        }
    }
```

**Deck Class**

```
public static class Deck {
    private static ArrayList<Card> cards;
     Deck() {
         cards=new ArrayList<Card>();
            for (int a=0; a<=3; a++){
                    for (int b=0; b<=12; b++){
                       cards.add( new Card(a,b) );
                     }
            }
            Collections.shuffle(cards, new Random());
            Collections.shuffle(cards, new Random(System.nanoTime()));
            //double shuffle for randomness
     }
     public Card drawFromDeck(){       
            return cards.remove( 0 );
     }
     public int getTotalCards(){
            return cards.size();
     }
}
```

**`PSVM()` and `rules` declaration:**

```
private static List<String> rules;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {     
    setGameRules(new File("rules.txt"));
    playGame(getNum("How many people are going to play","Number of Players"));
}
```

**`setRules()` Method:**

```
/**
* Rules are not hard-coded because people often have different ones,
* Therefore I made an easily editable rules.txt file.
* Also my rule file has formatting in using the \n,
* However when the file is read it is read as \ and n
* Hence why I used the replaceAll( "\\\\n","\n");
*/
private static void setRules(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    rules = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset());
    for(int i=0; i!=rules.size(); i++){
        rules.set(i, rules.get(i).replaceAll( "\\\\n","\n"));
    }
}
```

**`getNum()` Method:**

```
//This method was left as getNum because I will use it later for a Main Menu
private static int getNum(String prompt,String title) {
    return Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,prompt,title,3));
}
```

**`playGame()` Method:**

```
private static void playGame(int players) {
    int playerTurn;
    int choice;
    int kings=0;
    Card cardDrawn;
    Deck deck=new Deck();
    while(true){//loop to run the game till the 4th king is drawn
        playerTurn=0;
        while (playerTurn!=players){//used to give each player a turn
            choice=getChoice("Player "+(playerTurn+1),
                             "Would you like to skip or draw?","Draw","Skip","Exit");

            if (choice==0){
                cardDrawn=deck.drawFromDeck();
                System.out.println(cardDrawn);
                kings+=showCard(cardDrawn,kings,playerTurn+1);     
                playerTurn++;
            }                   
            else if(choice==1)
                playerTurn++;              
            else
                System.exit(0);                                    
         }//Turn reset loop
    }//continuous loop
}
```

**`getChoice()` Method:**

```
//this method is used so that I can reuse it later in the main menu.
private static int getChoice(String title, String prompt,
                             String a, String b, String c) {
    Object[] options = { a, b, c};
    return JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, prompt, title,0,2,
                                        null,options,options[0]);
    }
```

**`showCard()` Method:**

```
//The method name was originally checkIfKing(), I think this is better?
private static int showCard(Card a, int kings, int player) {
    if(a.rank==12)//checks if the card is a King
        if(kings==3){//checks if the card is the final King
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Player "+player+" has Drawn the Final King\n\n"
                    + "Restart the Program to Play again",a.toString(),1);
            System.exit(0);
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Player "+player+
                    " has drawn the "+a.toString()+"\n"
                    + "Which is King "+(kings+1)+"/4\n\n"
                    +rules.get(a.rank),a.toString(),1);
            return 1;
        }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Player "+player+
                " has drawn the "+a.toString()+"\n\n"
                + rules.get(a.rank),a.toString(),1);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the game loop runs until the 4th king is drawn (per comments), then why is the loop condition `while(true)`? If the loop condition was based on the 4th king being drawn you wouldn't need a comment there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has exceptionally tight coupling between the business code (the actual implementation of the game) and the user interface code. This means I can't easily reuse your code e.g. to play it on the command line instead of the GUI you have implemented.

You can achieve this seperation by defining an interface for all UI operations. In your `main`, you can then decide which UI implementation you want to use.

```
interface UserInterface {
  public int     numberOfPlayers();
  public boolean playerWantsToDrawCard(int player);  // if false: skip
  public void    showCard(Card card, int player, boolean last);
}
```

Your existing methods would then be refactored into a `GraphicalUserInterface implements UserInterface`. Note that this is a *different* abstraction than yours – the implementation you have shown abstracts over *what* is shown, but hardcodes *how* this is done. I'd rather do this the other way round.

With that new interface, your `playGame` would be changed to:

```
private static void playGame(UserInterface ui) {
    int players = ui.numberOfPlayers();
    int kings = 0
    Deck deck = new Deck();

    while (!deck.isEmpty()) {
        for (int player = 0; player < players; player++) {
            // players do not have to draw a card
            if (!ui.playerWantsToDrawCard(player)) {
                continue;
            }

            Card drawnCard = deck.draw();

            if (drawnCard.getRank() == Rank.KING) {
                kings++;
            }
            ui.showCard(drawnCard, player, kings == 4 || deck.isEmpty());

            // exit if we've seen all kings
            if (kings == 4) {
               return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While this assumes some further changes (e.g. to the `Deck` API), the main point is that the business logic doesn't have to deal with UI directly. Other important changes are:

- I use a `for` loop to iterate through all players instead of obfuscating this through another `while` loop.
- I declare my variables in the tightest scope possible. The `drawnCard` is not needed outside the inner loop, so I declare it there. As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't declare variables without initializing them directly.

One thing that isn't immediately obvious, but I let the `ui.showCard` method figure out wether this card was a king, and wether this was the last king. The only hint I have to provide is whether this was the last card in the game.

---

One thing I haven't explained yet is `Rank.KING`. In your original code, you have hardcoded `12`, which doesn't explain anything to a reader of the code. Currently, you specify the suit and rank of each card using integers. This is arguably wrong, and you should be using an enum:

```
enum Rank {
  ACE   ("Ace"),
  TWO   ("2"),
  THREE ("3"),
  FOUR  ("4"),
  FIVE  ("5"),
  SIX   ("6"),
  SEVEN ("7"),
  EIGHT ("8"),
  NINE  ("9"),
  TEN   ("10"),
  JACK  ("Jack"),
  QUEEN ("Queen"),
  KING  ("King");

  String name;

  Rank(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Ditto for `Suit`. Now our `Card` looks like

```
class Card {
  private Rank rank;
  private Suit suit;

  public String toString() {
    return rank.toString() + " of " + suit.toString();
  }

  ...
}
```

with the remaining methods having updated their types. Using enums allows for more type safety, and automatic additions like comparability and a iterable view of all possible values. This allows us to construct the deck like

```
cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
  for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
    cards.add(new Card(suit, rank));
  }
}
Collections.shuffle(cards, new Random());
```

Btw, shuffling once is “random” enough, and additional shuffling does not increase randomness. If you need a true cryptography-grade entropy source, the builtin pseudo-random number generator which `new Random()` gives you is *not sufficient*. But for the purpose of this game, its usage is quite allright.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have implemented a few code changes. 

However, if I use an enum for the rank how will I call the rule for that card?

Look at how this outputs:
`display("Player "+player+" has drawn the "+card+"\n\n"+rules.get(a.rank),card);`

I built a display method to make it easier to use a custom UI.

Comment: I added a `getRule()` method that uses the `for(Rank rank: Rank.value())` to iterate through the ranks with an `if(card.rank==rank)` then call the rule with the counter at that point. Works like a charm.

Comment: @KyleMHB Sorry, I didn't see that problem when I wrote my code. I think there is an `ordinal()` method on enum constants that returns the position – use it as an index.

Comment: Ah man... Thats so simple! `ordinal();` works much better. I made like this snazzy little iterative check I even felt clever :(

Answer (score 1):

[Following from this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/32284/30349)
These changes were made:

**`Enum`s Added for both Rank and Suit:**

```
enum Rank {
    ACE   ("Ace"),
    TWO   ("2"),
    THREE ("3"),
    FOUR  ("4"),
    FIVE  ("5"),
    SIX   ("6"),
    SEVEN ("7"),
    EIGHT ("8"),
    NINE  ("9"),
    TEN   ("10"),
    JACK  ("Jack"),
    QUEEN ("Queen"),
    KING  ("King");
    String name;
    Rank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
} 

enum Suit {
    HEARTS      ("Hearts"),
    DIAMONDS    ("Diamonds"),
    SPADES      ("Spades"),
    CLUBS       ("Clubs");
    String name;
    Suit(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**`Card Class` changed:**

```
public static class Card {
    private Rank rank;
    private Suit suit;

    Card(Suit suit, Rank rank){
            this.rank=rank;
            this.suit=suit;
    }
    public @Override String toString(){
              return rank.toString() + " of " + suit.toString();
    }
}
```

**`Deck Class` was changed:**

```
public static class Deck {
    private static ArrayList<Card> cards;
     Deck() {
         cards=new ArrayList<Card>();
            for (Suit suit : Suit.values()){
                    for (Rank rank : Rank.values()){
                       cards.add( new Card(suit,rank));
                     }
            }
            Collections.shuffle(cards, new Random());
            Collections.shuffle(cards, new Random(System.nanoTime()));
            //this double shuffle STILL provided me with better results.
     }
     public Card drawFromDeck(){       
            return cards.remove(0);
     }
}
```

**`playGame()` Method Changed:**

```
private static void playGame(int players) {
    int kings=0;
    Deck deck=new Deck();
    while(true){//Its impossible to reach the end of the deck so I stuck with this
        for (int playerTurn=0;playerTurn!=players;playerTurn++){//changed from a while
            int choice=getChoice("Player "+(playerTurn+1),
                             "Would you like to skip or draw?",
                             "Draw","Skip","Exit");

            if (choice==0){
                Card cardDrawn=deck.drawFromDeck();
                kings+=checkIfKing(cardDrawn,kings,playerTurn+1);  
            }                   
            else if(choice==2)
                System.exit(0);                                    
         }//forloop
    }//continuous loop
}
```

**`showCard()` Method renamed to `checkIfKing()`:**

The problem here was that previously to display the rule for the card picked I used `rules.get(a.rank)` as `a.rank` was an `int` that matched the position of that card in the `rules` list. so I created a `getRule()`

```
private static int checkIfKing(Card a, int kings, int player) {
    String card=a.toString();
    if(a.rank==Rank.KING)//easier to read using enums
        if(kings==3){
            display("Player "+player+" has Drawn the Final King\n\n"+
                    getRule(a)+"\n\n"+
                    "Restart the Program to Play again",card);
            System.exit(0);
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            display("Player "+player+" has drawn the "+card+"\n"
                    + "Which is King "+(kings+1)+"/4\n\n"
                    +getRule(a),card);
            return 1;
        }
    else{
        display("Player "+player+" has drawn the "+card+"\n\n"
                    +getRule(a),card);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**`getRule()` Method created:**

<strike>Made a clever little adaption using a for loop and a counter</strike>
`ordinal();` was used.

```
private static String getRule(Card card){
    return rules.get(card.rank.ordinal());   
}
```

**`display()` Method was created:**

This was made to make it a bit easier to use your own UI like amon wanted. Its not overly helpful bu this program is built for JOptionPane anyway. And it neatens up my code in the other methods.

```
private static void display(String prompt, String title) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,prompt,title,1);
}
```

Comment: Loose coupling isn't "helpful" in terms of "getting the thing to work" - Mark Seeman accurately depicts tight coupling as a hairdryer that's hardwired into a cheap hotel room's wall; with loose coupling you have a socket instead, and changing the hairdryer for another one or plugging a laptop instead isn't complicated anymore. And it makes cleaner code, but that's almost a side-effect! :)